# What are strong examples of programming languages whose type systems don't embed into their native type theory?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, dependent-types

Given a typical popular programming language, its [native type theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.04672) is a dependent type theory which describes invariants, preconditions, predicates, and other generalizations of typical type-system features. The title says it all: what are some strong examples of popular languages which have a type system that *can't* be (naturally?) embedded into their native type theory?

For what it's worth, I can't think of any examples whatsoever. Static types can be embedded. Object protocols and duck-typed constraints can be embedded too. Hoare logic can be embedded as well.

("Strong" here means that I'm not asking for a completely open listing, just well-known or easy-to-express examples which could possibly serve as canonical counterexamples.)

Comment: Probably any language which is not type safe... like Java (https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/papers/Saraswat-javabug.html)

Comment: I think non-type-safe languages are fine too. Haskell's unsound type system embeds into Haskell's native type theory, for example. I would love to read a specific strong example of how Java's type system can't be embedded into Java's native type theory.

Comment: The question is, what is the meaning of "embed"? If you map Java's `int` into `int + exception + undefined behavior + segfault` then you're probably going to be successful (since AFAIKT the "native type theory" is just a logic of the operational semantics of the language)

Comment: I'll accept any of the definitions used in [this nLab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/embedding+of+categories); I'm not picky. I suppose I'm asking for examples of popular programming languages whose operational semantics don't line up with their type systems.